# R Encoding categorical variables joined by separator

Tags: r, one-hot-encoding

**The Context**

In my dataframe, I have a column that contains fixed responses to a question on alternatives to consumption at a restaurant. Respondents can choose **multiple** options at once if needed.

Here are the 9 unique answer options available to respondents for this question -

```
#Unique responses to question
unique_vector = c('Bring food from home',
                  'Buy from a supermarket',
                  'Buy from deli, bakery, coffee, or sandwich shop',
                  'Go home',
                  'Go out to a fast food outlet',
                  'Order food from outside',
                  'Snack between meals',
                  'Go out to a full service restaurant',
                  'Skip the meal')
```

After running the survey on 10 respondents, the resulting dataframe looks like this -

```
#Survey Dataframe
df= data.frame(
                          Id = c(1:10),

                          QUESTION=c(unique_vector[1],
                          paste0(unique_vector[1],',',unique_vector[2]),
                          paste0(unique_vector[1],',',unique_vector[2],',',unique_vector[2]),
                          paste0(unique_vector[4],',',unique_vector[5],',',unique_vector[1]),
                          paste0(unique_vector[3],',',unique_vector[1],',',unique_vector[9],',',unique_vector[7]),
                          paste0(unique_vector[5],',',unique_vector[6],',',unique_vector[8],',',unique_vector[1]),
                          unique_vector[3],
                          "",
                          paste0(unique_vector[5],',',unique_vector[6],',',unique_vector[8],',',unique_vector[1]),
                          "")
)
```

**My Objective**

I'd like to spread the `QUESTION` column such that **each unique response is an individual column in the dataframe.**

And then I'd like to **encode these responses** such that they are recorded as 1s (and no responses as 0s).

**My Attempt**

I tried to use the one-hot encoding package in R. But I am unable to figure out how to modify my code to separate concatenated responses.

```
#Attempt
library(onehot)
encoded_df = onehot(df[,2], stringsAsFactors=TRUE)
```

Any inputs here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rather doubt that it's the simplest way to do this, but result is correct:

```
library(tidyverse)

unique_vector %>%
  str_c(collapse = ')|(') %>%
  str_c('(', ., ')') %>%
  str_extract_all(df$QUESTION, ., simplify = TRUE) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  mutate(Id = row_number()) %>%
  gather(x, key, V1:V4) %>%
  mutate(val = 1) %>%
  spread(key, val, fill = 0) %>%
  select(-c(x, V1)) %>%
  group_by(Id) %>%
  summarise_all(~if_else(sum(.) > 0, 1, 0))
```

If the separator will be different than `,` (`,` also occurs in answers) it will be simpler to do, by spliting on this separator:

```
df %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  mutate(QUESTION = map(QUESTION, ~str_split(.x, ',')[[1]] %>% unique)) %>%
  unnest() %>%
  mutate(val = 1) %>%
  spread(QUESTION, val, fill = 0) %>%
  select(-V1)
```

Comment: Great response. Just that for one of the answer values that contains multiple commas, the code splits it up into different parts `Buy from deli, bakery, coffee, or sandwich shop`.

Comment: In the second answer - yes. I mentioned that. But in the first solution it doesn't.